# JMeter JSON Extractor как вытащить часть значения из длинного значения ключа?

Tags: jmeter

В ответ на запрос от сервера приходит json вида:

```
{
    "result": {
        "command": "new_window",
        "redirect_url": "start_launch.html?start_id=7210330451636039663&launch_id=bkZ2WlpAW0xYWgRCd3VCWkAYQzdFYlp6X1dXYFRXVF9KXx5rTnRb"
    },
    "error_text": "",
    "action_completed": "eval_action",
    "error": 0
}
```

Как использовать extractor, чтобы использовать ТОЛЬКО значение из launch_id= `bkZ2WlpAW0xYWgRCd3VCWkAYQzdFYlp6X1dXYFRXVF9KXx5rTnRb` в будущих запросах?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Никак, только значение аттрибута полностью.

Используйте [Regular Expression Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) или [Boundary Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-boundary-extractor)

Можно в 2 шага:

1. Вытаскиваете `redirect_url` c помощью JSON Extractor
2. А уже из переменной достаете значение этого `launch_id`

Но если вам не нужен `redirect_url` целиком то Boundary Extractor сработает и без JSON Extractor

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Великолепно! Спасибо!